# Inlining a function with Clojure macros

Tags: performance, compiler-construction, macros, clojure

More out of curiousity that anything else (but with the expectation that it might occasionally be a useful trick for performance tuning), is it possible to use Clojure macros to "inline" an existing function?

i.e. I would like to be able to do something like:

```
(defn my-function [a b] (+ a b))

(defn add-3-numbers [a b c] 
  (inline (my-function 
    a 
    (inline (my-function 
      b 
      c)))))
```

And have it produce (at compile time) exactly the same function as if I had inlined the additions myself, such as:

```
(defn add-3-numbers [a b c] 
  (+ a (+ b c)))
```

Comment: Did you look at `apply` function? http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/apply

Comment: apply works dynamically at runtime, I'm looking for something that performs the inlining at compile time....

Comment: `(read-string (clojure.repl/source-fn \`my-function))` seems like a good starting point!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In case you didn't know, you can define inlined functions using `definline`

```
(doc definline)
-------------------------
clojure.core/definline
([name & decl])
Macro
  Experimental - like defmacro, except defines a named function whose
  body is the expansion, calls to which may be expanded inline as if
  it were a macro. Cannot be used with variadic (&) args.
nil
```

Also checking the source,

```
(source definline)
-------------------------
(defmacro definline
  [name & decl]
  (let [[pre-args [args expr]] (split-with (comp not vector?) decl)]
    `(do
       (defn ~name ~@pre-args ~args ~(apply (eval (list `fn args expr)) args))
       (alter-meta! (var ~name) assoc :inline (fn ~name ~args ~expr))
       (var ~name))))
```

`definline` simply defines a `var` with meta-data `{:inline (fn definition)}`. So although its not exactly what you were asking but you can rebind the var with new metadata to get inlined behavior.

Comment: useful link - this definitely looks like a helpful tool in many situations. the key difference with what I'm looking for is that it seems to require the function to be explicitly defined as inline, whereas I want to be able to inline an arbitrary function

Comment: I have not looked into implementing it, but I hinted at a potential solution. You can try writing a macro that rebinds the functions var to one with metadata that contains the :inline tag. The key problem that would need to be solved is to ensure that the rebinding is done at compile time rather than runtime.